# Why is a Class faster in SwiftUI than a Struct? (with example)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

can someone more experienced or smarter than me please take a look at this example code?

I was struggling with performance issues using SwiftUI with an MTKView and found out that the Struct I was using to keep the bindings was the guilty one. After hours of searching and trying stuff, I found out that using a Class solved the performance issues. It introduces other issues though, like the UI not always updating everywhere, and all my sliders returning to zero when my macOS app window is minimised or has no focus.

Even though I understand the difference between value and reference types, and that copying a Struct each time takes CPU cycles, I don't understand why my Class values seem to be unreachable at times by the UI...

Here's the macOS example code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  SlowStructFastClass
//
//  Created by Michel Storms on 12/01/2021.
//

import SwiftUI

class VC {
    var s1: Double = 0.5
}

class VD: ObservableObject {
    @Published var s1: Double = 0.5
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var valueStruct: Double = 0.5
    @State var valueClass = VC()
    @ObservedObject var valueClassObserved = VD()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("STRUCT")
            Slider(value: $valueStruct)
            Text("\(self.valueStruct)")
            
            Text("CLASS")
            Slider(value: $valueClass.s1)
            Text("\(self.valueClass.s1)")
            
            Text("CLASS - OBSERVABLEOBJECT")
            Slider(value: $valueClassObserved.s1)
            Text("\(self.valueClassObserved.s1)")
        }
    }
}
```

I think this is the simplest I could make the example, yet there is still a big speed difference between struct and class binding-based sliders...

Any clues? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

(tested on a 2020 i5 MBP running Big Sur)

edit: I added a case where I use ObservableObject / ObservedObject as suggested by Raja Kishan. This improves the responsiveness of the UI, but is still noticeable slower than the Class example.

For those interested, here are 3 videos to compare the performance:

[example videos](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0m2o4VTzRyD12IkKj0BJptIqg#Class_vs_Struct)

This is literally on the same code, only the binding was chenged.

Comment: what do you mean by UI not always updating everywhere with the class?

Comment: If you move the class slider, the value is not updated. It does update in case you move the struct slider. It's probably more an issue of the ui not updating. It seems really weird to me, I don't know what I am missing here...

Comment: Your missed to use ObservableObject. ```class VC: ObservableObject {
    @Published var s1: Double = 0.5
}``` and in struct ```@ObservedObject var valueClass = VC()```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject

Comment: Thanks for suggestion that. In my app, however, this still causes a slowdown that is big enough to make it unusable for my case where the slider updates properties of an image which is refreshed at 60fps. Even with one @Published slider value the slowdown vs a non-published class  is still noticeable in my example...